# Django: cannot save data from Form in DB

Tags: python, django

I've been following a tutorial, but making small changes, doesn't allow me to save the form in DB.

However, I know the model is correct because I can save objects from within shell.

I'm not getting any error, after submitting I'm redirected to the home page.

But if I submit form and then go to the admin, I see the registered model, but with no records on in (except the ones saved through shell).  Howcome?

**models.py:**

```
class TamaniosCantidades(models.Model):
    TAMANIOS = (('498', '2" x 2"',), ('499', '3" x 3"',),
               ('500', '4" x 4"',), ('501', '5" x 5"',))

    CANTIDADES = (('100', '50',), ('100', '100',),
                ('150', '150',))

    tamanios = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TAMANIOS)
    cantidades = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CANTIDADES)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import TamaniosCantidades

class TamaniosCantidadesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TamaniosCantidades
        fields = ['tamanios', 'cantidades']
```

urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('productos/', views.productos),
    path('post_url/', views.post_treasure, name='post_treasure'),
    path('post_url_tamanioscantidades/', views.post_tamanioscantidades, name='post_tamanioscantidades'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    treasures = Treasure.objects.all()
    form = TreasureForm()
    tamanioscantidades_form = TamaniosCantidadesForm()
    return render(request, 'main_app/index.html', {'treasures': treasures,
                                                   'form': form,
                                                   'tamanioscantidades_form': tamanioscantidades_form})



def post_tamanioscantidades(request):
    tamanioscantidades_form = TamaniosCantidadesForm()
    if tamanioscantidades_form.is_valid():
        tamanioscantidades_form.save(commit = True)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**html:**

```
<div class="row">
                <form action="post_url_tamanioscantidades/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ tamanioscantidades_form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def post_tamanioscantidades(request):
    tamanioscantidades_form = TamaniosCantidadesForm()
    if tamanioscantidades_form.is_valid():
        tamanioscantidades_form.save(commit = True)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

This method creates a blank `TamaniosCantidadesForm`, which isn't valid, so it never gets saved.

You probably want to do something like `TamaniosCantidadesForm(request.POST)`, to actually fill in the form with the submitted data.

Comment: just a bonus question. it's necessary to use a different post url for different forms? As you can see, I'm using: 'post_url_tamanioscantidades/' and 'post_url/'.  Could I only use: 'post_url/'  to handle all my forms?

Comment: It's usual to handle the GET and POST processing of a single form in one view.